# Display RGB window in linux using OpenGL and Freeglut

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu-10.04, freeglut

I want to create a window covering my whole desktop screen with displaying colors RGB and then VIBGYOR. The color delay should be 1 second.
This is the code I have written but output is not as expected. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

```
#include<GL/freeglut.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );

    glutInitWindowSize(1280,1024);
    glutCreateWindow("Displays");
    glutFullScreen();   

    glClearColor (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);      //Red
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0,1,0,0);              //Green
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0,0,1,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);           //Blue
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0.933, 0.510, 0.933, 0.0);     //violet
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0.294, 0.000, 0.510, 1);       //Indigo
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0,0,1,1);              //Blue
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(0,0.502,0,1);          //Green
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(1,1,0,1);              //Yellow
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(1,0.647,0,1);          //Orange
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);              //Red
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    sleep(1);   

glutMainLoop();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the display mode with `GLUT_DOUBLE` ([double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)), you need to add `gluSwapBuffers()` every time you're finished working with the buffer and want to display it.

```
...
glClearColor(1,0,0,1);              //Red
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glutSwapBuffers();
sleep(1);   
...
```

[Difference between single buffered(GLUT_SINGLE) and double buffered drawing(GLUT_DOUBLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28315492/2498790)

> When using GL_SINGLE, you can picture your code drawing directly to the display.
>
> When using GL_DOUBLE, you can picture having two buffers. One of them is always visible, the other one is not

[glut examples](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html)

[nehe's legacy tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/)

[What is the nicest way to close GLUT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061297/2498790)

> void glutLeaveMainLoop ( void );

Comment: Thanks, That worked. But I wanted to know the difference between the GLUT_DOUBLE and GLUT_SINGLE Macro, because in both cases it worked.
Also, I want to write some Text before the appearance of 1st color display in the same window.
I went through this link to get understand it but it didn't work well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538661/how-do-i-draw-text-with-glut-opengl-in-c

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R I've added some link, about the difference has been already answered, I also added some glut example which should help you about the text (and glut in general) and a reference to some easy GL tutorial (old but still good for learning purpose)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very helpful. Can you please tell me how to **Exit** the window after displaying everything?

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R take a look at glut examples, [abgr.c](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/abgr.c) for instance, it use `glutKeyboardFunc(Key)` to register a key handler, in the `Key` handler check for the `ESC` key, `case 27`

Comment: The original `glut` implementation has some limitation, one of them was the *main loop* never returning, `freeglut` implement `glutLeaveMainLoop` which should be used instead of `exit`. [glut-and-freeglut](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/glut-and-freeglut/)

Comment: Thanks, quite helpful... :)

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R in your case just remove `glutMainLoop();` and the application will exit.

Comment: Well, I tried that, but after removing, a window pops up and disappears very quickly.

Comment: Weird, it work for me, the sleeps keep the window opened till the color sequence is finished. You need a *MainLoop* if you need to handle user input, keys, mouse or timer events.

Comment: I will recheck my program once.